How to attach a DMG with different mount AND browse name?
I have a DMG foo.dmg which when I attach it via
hdiutil attach foo.dmg

appears in the Terminal under path /Volumes/foo and in the Finder side bar as "foo".
Now when attaching the DMG I want to change the name under which the DMG appears. I tried
hdiutil attach -mountpoint bar foo.dmg

and the DMG appears in Terminal in the filessystem as /Volume/bar. So far so good. But in the Finder (for "browsing") the DMG is still listed as "foo".
How can I call hdiutil and change both names, the filesystem volume name and the Finder browse name?
Side note:
The DMG(s) I want to treat like this are read-only DMGs, so they cannot be mounted with the -readwrite option to use diskutil rename` to rename the browse name permanently. (Thanks to @David Anderson for pointing out this principal method.)

Updated Answer
The Finder application posts the name of a mounted volume. This is stored in the volume itself. If the volume is mounted read-only then the name cannot be changed. So, your question is asking how to change something you have stated you don't want changed.
Original Answer
I do not believe the hdiutil command can change the name of a volume. You would need to use the diskutil command instead. In your case, you would need to enter the following.
hdiutil attach -mountpoint bar foo.dmg
diskutil rename ./bar bar

Although the standard practice is to mount in the /Volumes folder. Therefore, I would recommend the following.
hdiutil attach -mountpoint /Volumes/bar foo.dmg
diskutil rename /Volumes/bar bar

Note that you only need to do the rename once. If you keep the volume name of bar, then the next time you attach you can just enter the following.
hdiutil attach foo.dmg


David, good suggestion, thanks. Only thing making this not ideal is that it changes the DMG and these DMGs are meant as archives, so it would be nice to keep time stamp and CRC check flag. -- Will update question to clarify.
